# Variance calculation with Matlab

Tags: matlab, variance

I don't understand why MATLAB does not normalize the data by its size while computing the variance. Ex :

```
a=[1 2 3]; 
var(a);   %//  1
```

However we know that the fundamental definition of the variance is :

```
variance(a) = ((a(i)-mean(a))^2) / size(a)  %// here size(a)=3
%//this formula gives a variance equal to 2/3
```

any idea?

Comment: Look at [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html#bundkwe-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained in [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html):

[image]

MATLAB is uses the formula for [unbiased *sample* variance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Variance#/Population_variance_and_sample_variance) by default

Comment: thank you for the explanation